# How to decorate type-safe component with withNavigation

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

I have React component, which uses withNavigation decorator.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

@withNavigation
export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (<View><Text>test</Text></View>);
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error:(5, 2) TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<NavigationInjectedProps>'.
  Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<NavigationInjectedProps>'.
    Type 'typeof Foo' provides no match for the signature '(props: NavigationInjectedProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

I suppose I should specify some interface for component's props, but it's hard for me to interpret this error.

What interface should component have?

Answer (score 4):

```
import { NavigationInjectedProps, withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'

type FooOwnProps = {}

@withNavigation
class Foo extends React.Component<FooOwnProps & NavigationInjectedProps> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (<View><Text>test</Text></View>);
  }
}
export default withNavigation(Foo);
```

I'm pretty sure that withNavigation is not decorator, and render is not public method